# railsでeachで一定の値でグループ化？した情報を出力する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rails初心者です。
rails５で勉強中です。

都道府県、駅、路線名が別々もモデルになっておりアソシエーションを組んでおります。

```
#########モデル#########
#pref.rb（都道府県）
class Pref < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stations
end

#station.rb（駅名）
class Station < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pref
  belongs_to :line, foreign_key: 'line_id', primary_key: 'line_id'
end

#line.rb（路線名）
class Line < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stations, class_name: 'Station', foreign_key: 'line_id', primary_key: 'line_id'
end


#########コントローラー#########
#stations_controller.rb
class StationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pref_name = Station.find_by(pref_id: params[:area_id])
    @stations = Station.where(pref_id: params[:area_id])
  end

  def show
  end

end


#########ビュー#########
#stations/index.html.erb

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1><%= @pref_name.pref.name %>｜<%= @stations.count %>駅｜Stations#index</h1>
      <p>Find me in app/views/stations/index.html.erb</p>

          <% @stations.each do |station| %>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading"><%= station.line.line_name %></div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                      <li class="list-group-item"><%= station.station_name %></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

DBはmysqlで
**prefsテーブル**
id:integer
pref_cd:integer
name:string

**stationsテーブル**
id:integer
pref_id:integer
station_cd:integer
station_name:string
line_id:integer

**linesテーブル**
id:integer
line_id:integer
line_name:string

現状は下記のような表示になってしまっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【山手線】
大崎
 【山手線】
五反田
 【山手線】
目黒
上記のようになっているのを…

【山手線】
大崎
五反田
目黒
山手線の駅が全部出力されると…
【南武線】
矢野口
稲城長沼
南多摩

と言った具合に路線でグルーピング？して出力したいです。
各駅が持っているline_id（線路のID）をグループ化してどうにかしてeachで回せないかと考えていますが答えがでません。
どのように処理すれば解決しますでしょうか？？？
ぜひともご教授お願い致します！！！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/99724

Comment: @htb おそらくマルチポストをする方はそもそもマルチポストが一般的にマナー違反だという認識がないと思いますので https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/マルチポストとはなんですか-何か問題があるのでしょうか など参考になるリンクをつけるのはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @ironsand 回答しようとする方への参考情報であり、質問者さんに向けたものではないです。

Answer (score 2):

`group_by`を使ってこのようにすると

```
@grouped_stations = @stations.group_by {|s| s.line.line_name}
```

以下のようなハッシュが得られます

```
{"山手線"=>[山手線の駅の配列], "南武線"=>[南部線の駅の配列]}
```

後はこのハッシュをよしなにループして表示すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: ご指摘機の方法で理想通りの表示がされました！ありがとうございます。